# Login with facebook error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to login with facebook but i am getting too many redirect error. Please help me how to fix it.

**I have tried Browser cookie clear does not work.**

```
<?php
require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// I think i am not getting user. So i get 0 in user.
if ($user) {

  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
        $username = $user_profile['name'];
        $uid = $user_profile['id'];
        $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $user = new User();

                $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_profile['id'].'/picture?type=large');
                $file = $_SESSION['SITE_IMG_PATH'].'userimage/'.$user_profile['id'].'.jpg';
                file_put_contents($file, $img);
                $userimage=$user_profile['id'].'.jpg';
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret,$userimage);

        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['frontuser_info'] = $userdata;

            $Qparam=$fid.''.$sid.''.$tid;

            header("Location: ".$_SESSION['APP_PATH']."".$Qparam);

        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {

    # There's no active session, let's generate one

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));

    # i think it is always coming here thats error.
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}

?>
```

Please see code and help me to fix this redirection error i am always going in else part thats error.

[image: Login with facebook error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]

Comment: add code. We already know how output of error looks like

Comment: @ricky add the code..can't tell anything looking at this page..

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @ricky-ponting I think your $user variable is empty, that's why your else condition works all the time with header redirecting to the same page as $login_url again empty there.

Comment: @AmitGupta but why can you guide please?

Comment: @Rickyponting I think there is some issue with your facebook plugin that's why response is not coming. Try https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Comment: I had to do what justinkoh recommended with a few extra steps. I went to facebook.com/settings/basic to login. Then I got the same redirect loop timeout Then I pasted into the address bar: *[https://www.facebook.com/INSERTYOUR BUSINESS PAGE URL/settings/basic/](http://)* It took me to a page that displayed a "Page doesn't exist" banner, but I was able to click on the Facebook icon in the top left to access my business page.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with your `Facebook Plugin`, that's why `$user` coming as 0. There can be many other reason behind it too. You need to re-check your `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET` as well.

Most importantly, you need to follow below links and update accordingly.

https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Or

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was requesting *granted_scopes* along with redirecting to provider

then in callback - and as long as there are required scopes in array of *declined scopes*, i **re-requested** back but forgot to set *granted scopes* again, so i ended up in the **redirect loop** error between application and facebook. Maybe it's your case too.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with Facebook dashboard at the time of this writing.

You could wait for the fix or try skipping dashboard by editing the url by replacing "/dashboard/" with "/settings/basic/".

PS: I had checked browser extensions, cleared browsing history and cookies, disabled Web shields to no avail, only this worked.